# "What can cause this" questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently came across the following question - [Promise error The message port closed before a reponse was received](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43154963/8230810) - essentially, it is asking "I have this exception caused by a Chrome extension error somewhere. Do you know what can cause this error?". It has over 16.4k views, many positive votes (+28/-0), and the accepted answer is also highly received (+27/-0) and is kept up to date.

However, the question is also full of answers which say something along the lines of "Mine was due to the XXXXX extension" and not much else.

What is the correct thing to be done about this question?

- Since the answer is seemingly "certain extensions cause this so disable your extensions one by one and see which is the culprit", should this question/answer be made into a Community Wiki containing a list of the known culprits at the end of the accepted answer? It looks like someone tried to do this already with a separate answer but it has been pretty much ignored.
- Is it even a problem that this question has many answers just stating "this extension caused my exception", and in which case should it just be left alone?
- Since there are apparently so many different answers, is this question actually too broad?
- Is there a more appropriate fourth course of action?

I'd love to get community input on this. At the time of writing, I haven't taken any action (flag for mod to consider making a community wiki, flag as too broad, etc) because it's not something I've seen before and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

"Correctness" is overrated.

In situations like this, where you're tied in knots over the rules, ask yourself a simple question:  **Does this post make Stack Overflow (and by extension, the Internet) a better or worse place?**

I think the answer to that is obvious here.

Comment: This answer is both correct **and** making the site a better place. That said, the posts on that page could probably stand a little bit of editing.

Comment: My moderation philosophy, stated far more succinctly than I ever could.

Comment: This answer seems to equate to the reasoning, "is it good or bad? if it's not bad, don't try to improve it", which seems absurd, rather like [your contribution to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596024/how-to-fix-this-declaration-has-no-storage-class-or-type-specifier-error#comment95988115_54596024) (to which I see you quietly removed my response). Is everything okay?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You voted to close that question.  Nothing precludes you from improving that question by editing instead of voting to close.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My voting record on the question (which is self-explanatory, by the way; the close reason links to a detailed exploration on how MCVEs should be constructed, and you know darned well that nobody else has enough information to make the MCVE _for_ the OP -- that's the whole point) is completely unrelated to the fact that you posted a snarky and unhelpful comment which is not only out of character but also the sort of thing that moderators historically tend to discourage. Then this answer. I'm genuinely concerned.

Comment: @Lightness I removed your comment and Robert's response in response to a flag. As far as the original comment goes (which Robert deleted himself), I hardly think telling the person to do as the error message says advises even rates on the snarkiness scale. I have no idea what point you're trying to make here. In no way do I see Robert making the argument that "if it's not bad, don't try to improve it". What does that even mean? You know full well that debug-my-code questions without MCVEs don't make the Internet a better place, so that's why you both voted to close.