# Are comments on the accepted answer with trivial new questions eligible for flagging as "no longer needed"?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

I have seen several times in my answers, when the author of the question asks a simple trivial question in the comments of the accepted answer as *Your suggestions solved the problem X, but how do I solve Y now?* I usually tend to ask them to start a new post if the question involves an altogether detailed answer, but for simple quick fixes, I usually reply it over the comments and then they just thank over the suggestions.

Is it acceptable to flag these comments which are *not* related to the original question, e.g. no mention of this new requirement in the original post as 'no longer needed'? I just had a few comments declined today for one of my posts. Would like to know more clarity on this.

Comment: I just don't understand a reason for the downvote on this question. After-all I was seeking for a site wide understanding on the right action to take. If this is a duplicate of a well discussed topic, feel free to link it. Otherwise it is very hard to fathom why would this be downvoted without a proper comment. Kind of conveys a statement to not ask about practices that are recommended to follow on the site

Comment: Didn't vote on it, but I could imagine a couple of reasons for someone else wanting to downvote it. For example: discussions about deleted and not deleted comments get tiresome, and are sometimes not viewed as _useful_. Or another: questions under an answer could be seen as _asking for clarification or improvements_, and mods shouldn't have to judge each of this cases in to see if the are really worth deleting or not. I'm sure more reasons could be thought of. And hypothetical reason for upvoting as well.

Comment: In any case, discussing individual votes is very rarely productive. And expecting comments explaining votes is a recipe for disappointment.

Comment: A concrete example is very important, no really good reason to skip it when you have one.  But in general, if you use the flag then be sure to do so *before* you answer the comment.  If you do it afterwards then it looks too much like the comment was relevant and should be kept.

Comment: @HansPassant: Are you suggesting that I should have flagged it before responding to the comment and not later? As I'd explained in the question, it is a pretty trivial detail which would hardly take a minute to help out which I did. What is wrong in just removing those comments? as such they won't be useful reading that post?

Comment: @yivi: Ok if that's the case, why not add a simple comment stating what you described and put this question on meta as off-topic or non-productive, so that I can get to know these topics are not relevant for discussion on meta?

Comment: I don't know why others users chose to comment or not. Comments and votes are optional, and users chose to use them for their own reasons. I was only especulating.

Comment: Hi, yes I was the first to downvote. I didn't have time to leave a lengthy comment as to why I did downvote. As far as I see it, comments don't mean much and users are perfectly able to ask a Y question on an X answer. You're also not obliged to answer them if you don't feel like answering the Y question. Flagging means that someone else needs to review the flag, which is just more work for a simple comment. Better to simply tell the user "nope, please create another question for this" or answer it. I sometimes take time to answer the Y question depending on how long it'll take.

Comment: If the user is asking a clarifying comment, why not edit your answer to include the comment and its answer? Then you've got the info in the right place (the answer), and mods can clean up the comments without losing any potentially helpful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I declined the flags you raised on this. I'm happy to explain my rationale, but don't take this as creating or implying any sort of general rule.

In the motivating case, the user asked you a follow-up question, you asked him to clarify, he did, and then you replied with a quick answer. That you were able to reply with a quick answer basically served as confirmation that it was a "simple" follow-up question, and thus a legitimate use of comments.

The user then asked yet another follow-up question, conceding that that one may have been off-topic. You responded to that by linking him to a Q&A on another site.

For those following along at home, here are the comments at the time of flagging:

> [image]

You raised a "no longer needed" flag on Delfin's last comment. I deleted this comment because, in my judgment, the question being asked there was utterly off-topic *and* (more importantly) unlikely to be helpful to others ("what is POSIX?" is either blindingly obvious and/or downright trivial to Google for). This deletion marked your flag as "helpful".

I declined "no longer needed" flags that you raised on Delfin's other two comments, because, as explained above, I determined that these were simple follow-up questions and thus legitimate uses of comments. I kept them because they were short enough that the noise volume wasn't a concern, and because I thought they might be of help to future readers. If one person has a follow-up question, it's very likely that others will have the same follow-up question. This is kinda the whole principle of Stack Overflow: one question, one answer, many beneficiaries.

Once again, [Hans's cynicism is pretty much right on the money](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380793/are-comments-on-the-accepted-answer-with-trivial-new-questions-eligible-for-flag#comment674320_380793):

> …in general, if you use the flag then be sure to do so *before* you answer the comment.  If you do it afterwards then it looks too much like the comment was relevant and should be kept.
>   – Hans Passant

Not only did your response make it look like the comment was relevant, but the fact that you provided a response which was appreciated by the asker made it look like deleting this content would be making the Internet a worse place. Given [my moderation strategy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379967/366904), that was a natural reason to dismiss the flag and leave the comment in place.

(Note that moderators cannot mark a comment flag "helpful", but still decline to delete the comment. Well, technically, we *could* delete the comment, which would mark the flag as "helpful", then *undelete* the comment, which wouldn't change the disposition of the flag, but that's way too much work for something as insignificant as a comment flag.)

Honestly, I don't really understand what motivates people to flag these types of comments, especially with such determination that they will flag them *multiple times* when they don't get removed. How are these comments hurting anything? Why are you so motivated to get them removed? Maybe I'm missing something and you can explain this to me.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. My general ideology would be to clean up comments in an accepted answer, unless there are really helpful facts discussed in the comments. The fact that you felt the comments in my post would be helpful to readers is what separated our thought process. I felt it was too trivial to be present on the site. Thanks and I’ll remember this next time for my comment flagging