# This question was perhaps erroneously deleted by a ♦ moderator

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This question was deleted by a ♦ mod as "off-topic" on the 18th of February:

> [jwt: 'module' object has no attribute 'encode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198428/jwt-module-object-has-no-attribute-encode)

Having encountered this exact issue today I found both the question and answer are in fact useful (and given the number of upvotes on both the question and highest voted answer, others did too).

I propose that the question be re-instated.

Comment: I've undeleted it to at least allow for a discussion about whether it should remain.

Comment: Cheers Brad, appreciated.

Comment: I think the answer with +60/-0 disproves the "this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers" part of the close reason.

Comment: I finally reopened and protected the question. I am not a python expert, but the quesiton and answers look useful enough for me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - thanks. The highest upvoted answer solved the problem for me, also the question has pretty decent google-juice for the search term `module 'jwt' has no attribute 'encode'` (1st page, 3rd result...for me anyway)

Comment: @Kev Well, sometimes it seems that even ♦ mods strech their powers overzealously and too far. On the other hand we're all humans after all (which includes error prone decisions and assumptions). :-P

Comment: I highly disagree with this type of content being deleted. Sometimes, an explanation of some obscure fact that is hard to notice can save hours if not days of time. There are tens of thousands of posts which need actioning more than something like this. I am curious how it was discovered for deletion in the first place.

Comment: @Kev - re: "google-juice", a large reason that Stack Overflow is so popular is for its quality content for error message searches, which is just another reason to keep this post.

Comment: Hoooboyyyyy there's a mod not having a good day today...

Comment: It was a misunderstanding based on the [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33214351/3956566) that it wasn't reproducible and had no solution. Sorry about that.

Comment: @YvetteColomb - easily done, and have done the same when I had my ♦.

Comment: How did you *find* the deleted question out of curiosity?

Comment: @Chris_Rands - it was via a google search for `module 'jwt' has no attribute 'encode'`.

Comment: @YvetteColomb to be fair, I almost made the same mistake after opening that question in a tab, and visiting it an hour later, the "self-answer" was the one that was on top by my "oldest" sort order

Comment: I set my Google results with 100 results per page. That way, everything is always on the first page.

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier: Sample how-to: *[Display More Than 10 Results in Google Search](https://www.gtricks.com/google/display-more-results-search/)* (essentially adding "`num=100`" to the query URL)

Comment: I think the real issue is why on Earth it is so easy for the good system to allow a good question to be closed ?

Comment: Still, why is the self answer still there? Surely it doesn't help anybody.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Was the sort order of answers a contributing factor? When I looked at the question just now (for some reason I had it on 'oldest' instead of 'votes'), I initially thought that 0-voted self-answer was the only (not deleted) answer, so I first wondered why it was important to preserve.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel to be honest I can't remember exactly and it took me a while to back track to work out what I was thinking. I don't think I realised there were a couple of highly upvoted answers. I wouldn't have deleted it. I change my sort order *a lot* even within the one day, depending what I'm looking for. So it doesn't mean the most upvoted will be on the top. Still my mistake for not being thorough enough.

Comment: @Will it *was* a bad mod day, but there's always a new day :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I agree with you and the commenters who have expressed concern regarding this question's deletion. The number one rule when moderating Stack Overflow—whether as a regular community member or as a diamond moderator—should be not to destroy value. In other words, [don't make the Internet a worse place by removing useful information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379967).

In this case, it is pretty clear that the information is useful, based solely on the vote counts. The question is scored at +26/−0, while the top answer is scored at +63/−0. *None* of the 13,000 viewers found either of these to be unclear, not useful, or otherwise not helpful. That's a pretty strong signal, and overriding it must be done with *extreme* care.

[Yvette has already copped to having made a mistake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381001/this-question-was-perhaps-erroneously-deleted-by-a-moderator#comment675757_381001) here. She handled a "not an answer" flag on [the self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33214351), and after reading that answer, concluded that the question was due to an issue that could not be reproduced and thus this Q&A would not be helpful to others in the future. There's a close reason specifically for that (under list of "off-topic" reasons), and it's a perfectly valid reason to close and/or remove questions.

When moderators are cleaning up low-quality answers, it's important that they also take the time to see if the question itself might be responsible for attracting those low-quality answers. If so, the question itself should be cleaned up, not just the answers. In other words: focus on the cause, not the symptoms.

This turned out to be a bit of an edge case, though. Despite the unhelpful self-answer, this problem *does* seem to be something that strikes a large number of people, and *was* resolved in a way that is massively helpful to future viewers. As such, the deletion was a simple mistake, and has since been corrected. Thanks for bringing it to our attention; please put away your pitchforks now. :-)

In the future, it's worth noting that mistakes like this can also be brought to the moderator team's attention by raising a custom flag on the deleted question (possible as long as you have [privileges to see deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)) or on another question. I don't mean this suggestion as a way of *discouraging* posting on Meta when you actually want community input, but sometimes [the Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) is undesirable.

Comment: Thanks Cody. re: pitchforks.....I hope folks don't think I was singling out Yvette. I endeavoured to make language in the request to undelete/re-open as neutral as possible. Have been there and done that myself when I was a mod and know what it's like on the other side :)

Comment: The pitchforks comment wasn't referring to you specifically, @Kev, but more to some of the other comments on the question. One made reference to diamond mods abusing their powers. It was flagged, but I declined the flag to avoid the accusation that diamond mods were abusing our powers by removing criticism. I totally understand both sides here. As a moderator, I know what it's like to make a mistake. As a community member, I hate to see value destroyed, whether by mistake or on purpose.

Comment: Apropos custom flags.....my concern was that the flag queue was congested and a flag might not get processed for several days perhaps causing what I thought was a very useful answer to disappear from google.